# SELECT stament subquery

Tags: sql

I have a SQL employee table like the following:

```
╔════╦═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ ID ║    NAME     ║ TITLE     ║ HIRE_DATE ║  MANAGER ID ║
╠════╬═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ John Smith  ║ Manager   ║ 15-JUN-15 ║      NULL   ║
║  2 ║ Jim Jimmers ║ Associate ║ 23-AUG-15 ║       1     ║
╚════╩═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

I would like to return the following:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦══════════════╗
║    NAME     ║ TITLE     ║ HIRE_DATE ║ MANAGER NAME ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬══════════════╣
║ John Smith  ║ Manager   ║ 15-JUN-15 ║      NULL    ║
║ Jim Jimmers ║ Associate ║ 23-AUG-15 ║ John Smith   ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

I'm just really having problems pulling the name from the manager. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's a simple join..

Answer (score 3):

Use a join not a subquery:

```
select t1.name, t1.title, t1.hire_date, t2.Name from table t1 left join table t2 on t1.managerid = t2.id
```

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You are right. Thanks for pointing out that. Have changed my answer

Answer (score 3):

It should be something like this:

```
SELECT E1.NAME, E1.TITLE, E1.HIRE_DATE, E2.NAME
FROM employee AS E1 LEFT OUTER JOIN employee AS E2 ON (E2.ID=E1.MANAGER_ID)
```